# how to execute a method BackgroundAudioPlayer fastforward?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, background-audio

Tell me please how to execute a method BackgroundAudioPlayer fastforward?

That is, how to do that when you long press the button, fast forward, and then release the button, the track nchinal play, in general as well as buttons work in the locked mode.

If you long press call as follows:

```
private void btnNext_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.FastForward();
        }
```

The track is scrolled to the end and pops up an error.

Comment: it seems that agent Fastforward and Rewind doesnot work as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your desired behavior?  You probably need some code on the MouseLeftButtonUp event to call Play to resume the playing of the current audio track.